# Rendering as plain text

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am using the react wrapper with the latest version of tabulator.
All styles seem to be missing, so everything is rendering as concatenated plain text. 
Is there a step I'm missing other than what is in the quick start? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed to include the css imports!

```
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css'; // required styles
import 'react-tabulator/lib/css/tabulator.min.css'; // theme
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks -- I had the css but not the styles -- probably a cut-paste error or accidental import deletion.

Comment: if you agree with Shmili's answer, would you mind marking it as the answer to help others out in future